# From which version "vclunit.pas" changed to "Vcl.vclunit.pas"?

Tags: delphi, components

I made a component in Delphi 2007 and now I want to make it work with new versions of Delphi so I must change the uses from
 `uses Controls;`
to
 `uses {$if CompilerVersion > 21}Vcl.Controls{$else}Controls{$ifend};`.
But I don't know the compiler version I must write. Anyone knows it?

Comment: Or you could ensure `Vcl` is defined in the project's Unit Scope Names and not have to worry about these conditionals.

Comment: @Jerry that option is available to app developers, but not for component developers. The component should not make assumptions about the app which consumes it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Very true.

Comment: That "unit scope names" feature is very questionable. I'd better you to employ `-NS` switch to the modern version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unit scope names were introduced in XE2. And XE2 is compiler version 23. So the conditional is:

```
{$if CompilerVersion >= 23}
```